# remove duplicates from ng-repeat

Tags: arrays, angularjs

```
<span ng-repeat="x in user.role">
    <span ng-repeat= "name in x.permissions">
        <input type="checkbox" name={{name}} id="{{$index}}" ng-model="user.checkpermission.checked[$index]" ng-change="ChangedPermission(user)">
        <label for="{{name}}">{{name}}</label>
        <br>
    </span>
</span>

<div class="row">
    <span class="error-message" ng-if= "!user.checkpermission.checked">Please select a checkbox</span>
</div>
```

`user.role` is an array of objects. In each of those objects,  I have an array called `permissions`.I get repeating values for `name` after collectively iterating through permissions array of every object as one array may have just 'show' and other might have 'Show', 'Delete'.

How do I display only unique values for name and get rid of the duplicates here?

Comment: I think you should do this repeat other way around. Aka ng-repeat of users, and inside of it ng-repeat of role, and then permissions.

Comment: this code might help `ng-repeat="x in user.role track by x.permissions.name" `

Comment: It did not help. @Anita

Comment: @loan : But how do expect it to remove the dupes?

Comment: This is bad practice, clean up your data from either the data source or in the controller, NEVER in the view.